# What needle and thread to repair backpack strap

Tags: clothing

I need to repair a ripped seam on my large rucksack by hand.  The repair should be strong enough to hold around 20-25kg.  What thread is appropriate, and what kind of needle and stitch should be used?

Comment: This could be a question for https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Waxed thread is stronger than unwaxed.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the material. For heavy canvas, or leather reinforcements, [a hand-awl that stitches like a sewing machine](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B076796Y6P) is useful. These awls usually come with an assortment of needles and some waxed thread. *N.B.* The needles are brittle; do not exert sideways force on them.

For nylon and other lightweight fabric, medium nylon or carpet thread can be used with any sewing needle with large-enough eye. The important thing is to use enough stitches to cover any area likely to pull loose. Be sure to overcoat the stitched area with a sealant, both for waterproofing and to reduce likelihood of stitches pulling out. Though there are [commercial seam sealants](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0007RSG70), I've used urethane or vinyl cements successfully.

If it's an area likely to be abraded, e.g. bottom of pack, a bit of adhesive tent-patch tape or iron-on tape, carefully applied (don't melt a nylon pack!) makes the repair last longer.

Answer (score 0):

I would visit a shoe repair shop for a length of heavy thread for the job at hand. The cobbler would be a good person to consult for advice on the gauge and composition.

I would recommend a baseball stitch that you find along the seams of a leather-covered hard or soft baseball. The benefit of the stitch is that it pulls the edges together in a butt-splice that remains flat. The distance on either side of the seam can be varied to accommodate weakened fabric. The stitch also reduces the edges unravelling.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to a quilting or fabric shop, ask for upholstery thread. I'd consider using an [X-box stitch](https://sew4home.com/tips-resources/sewing-tips-tricks/how-sew-x-box-secure-straps-more) if you want it to look nice. Otherwise, you can [do it by hand](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Torn-Off+Backpack+Shoulder+Strap+Repair/40140) and make sure you reinforce the stitch.